# Store my password, and don't give it back to me for a certain time

Tags: passwords, user-accounts, password-management, password-protection, web-services

I have exams and I have to study very much. But, there are some web applications and social network sites that take too much time of mine.

I need an application (preferred a web application, a local tool would eventually make me try to hack it!) that would store passwords of my favorite website accounts, and won't give it back to me for a certain (user specified) time. With this service, I want to store passwords of both the both the website and the separate recovery mail account associated to it.

It must be trustworthy and it shouldn't give any error that would cause to lose my accounts forever.

Comment: A technological solution isn't going to help you. Get someone you trust (a parent?) to change the passwords and write them down on a piece of paper *they* keep until your exams are over.

Comment: What you are asking for isn't really possible. *Any* (ok, maybe not Google or Facebook) site could go down permanently at any time. In this kind of situation the best thing to do is practice self restraint. Or do as ChrisF sad and get a trusted person to help.

Comment: @ChrisF: Yes. My B-plan is that. I will generate a complex password, give half of it to a trusted friend.

Answer (score 1):

If you are seriously interested in keeping yourself away from social networks, you should either have your ISPs drop your internet connection or have somebody whom you trust to change all passwords, write them down somewhere and hand them over to you later.

A software solution most probably won't work, as you'll eventually would want to "take a peek".